# атрибуты товара в Woocommerce только для админа

Tags: woocommerce

Всем привет! Есть такой вопрос. Как в Woocommerce на странице товара вывести некоторые атрибуты, которые будут видны только админу? Чтобы посетители сайта их не видели.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете добавить проверку

```
if( current_user_can('manage_options') ){
    echo "Поля для админа";
}
```

Или

```
if( is_super_admin( get_current_user_id() ) ){
    echo "Поля для админа";
}
```